# Javascript update the existing object in array to the latest added object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-manipulation, array-filter

I have the following data format coming from websocket:

```
{
   "open":3581.7228390197174,
   "last":"19372.91592032353582908399403095245361328125",
   "high":10036.924161117426,
   "low":53750.85165594209,
   "volume":4885294,
   "timestamp":"1519709400000",
   "close":19372.915920323536
}
```

There is hundreds of this coming from websocket what I do right now is when I receive a message I pushed it to array so I have a collection of everything the data has date/time in 1 minute interval and there is a possibility that I can receive a 10 data in current minute it means same timestamp so I need to update the existing one in the collection so it won't be duplicated this is what I tried as of right now

```
var currentMinute = [];
var parsedData = JSON.parse(r.data);

parsedData.date = moment.utc(parseInt(parsedData.timestamp)).local();
parsedData.open = +parsedData.open;
parsedData.close = +parsedData.last;
parsedData.high = +parsedData.high;
parsedData.low = +parsedData.low;
parsedData.volume = +parsedData.volume;

dataArray.push(parsedData);

dataArray.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.date.valueOf() - b.date.valueOf();
});

var lastData = dataArray[dataArray.length - 1];

if (lastData.timestamp === parsedData.timestamp) {
  lastData.close = +parsedData.close;
  currentMinute.push(parsedData);
} else {
  var lastDataOfMinute = currentMinute[currentMinute.length - 1];
  currentMinute = [];
}
```

What I plan to do is compare the very last data in the collection of all data that I received in ws then push it to a collection of current minute then if another data came in with different timestamp I will create a last data of that minute variable with the last data in array of current minute then clear the array then loop to that process but I cant get it to work I don't also know if I'm doing it the right way any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry my mistake i just updated the sample data above.

Comment: `currentMinute` isnt defined anywhere - did you miss some code from your question?

Comment: yes sorry about that ive updated the question.

Comment: Now, couldn't you theoretically use an object, with keys based on your timestamp and as value an array? The you could simply group all your data inside those arrays, and leave the manipulation part out until you need to do something with the data?

Comment: If you put example code and data on github I'll be happy to have a look.